# Logstash multiline xml filter

Tags: xml-parsing, logstash, logstash-configuration

I have a log file with events of the form

```
<ae cat="fixed" ts="2015-09-11T05:57:27.500-07:00">
 <s u="admin"></s>
</ae>
```

and I want to use the xml logstash filter on this file to parse it and get @cat=fixed

```
filter {
     multiline {
         pattern => '^<ae'
         negate => true
         what => "next"
         }
      xml {
          store_xml => "false"
          source => "message"
          xpath => [ "/ae/@cat", "cat" ]
       }
    }
```

This only gets the first line of the event. I have tried several things with negate 'false' or what 'previous' but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"If the line doesn't begin with <ae, keep it with the next line?"

Seems backwards.

Try:

```
 multiline {
     pattern => '^<ae'
     negate => true
     what => "previous"
 }
```

Note that it won't release the first message until the next one begin, so, for testing, always paste in at least two messages.

The output I get:

```
{
       "message" => "<ae cat=\"fixed\" ts=\"2015-09-11T05:57:27.500-07:00\">\n <s u=\"admin\"></s>\n</ae>\n",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-09-22T19:39:12.371Z",
          "host" => "0.0.0.0",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "multiline"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This does work either, I still get only the first line of the xml.

Comment: Added by output.  Maybe you have something else going on in your config.

Comment: Just to clarify, the above works, the issue was I was using vim to add logs to the test input file and I guess that messed up the way logstash remembered the state of my file and as a side effect only the first line of the file was read. Thank you